# How to teleport an entity with a specific name to a player in a specific gamemode in 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm using this command:

```
/execute @a[m=2] ~ ~ ~/tp @e[name="LeftClick"}
```

"LeftClick" being the name of a Villager that has one heart so I can test for if you left click, but I'm having trouble teleporting the Villager to the player in gamemode 2. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `/execute` at all:

```
/tp @e[name="LeftClick"] @a[m=2]
```

Comment: this is in what i was going for, but I forgot about the `@a[m=2]` part.  this is the best answer, not mine.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/tp @e[name="LeftClick"]` `@a[gamemode=adventure,limit=1]`